# Rspec Test Controller download excel Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

Hi I tried to add test to my controller I have a method that download a excel file

In my method controller i have this code.

```
def  download_syllabus_evaluation_system
    @syllabus_programs = SyllabusProgram.match_course_coordinator.actives.order(:id)

    name_file = "Syllabus_evalution_system"
    setHeaderExportExcel(name_file) 
    respond_to do |format|
      format.excel { render template: '/syllabuses/excel/syllabus_evaluation_system', layout: 'report/excel/template', status: :ok}
    end
  end
```

And this method that set Header

```
def setHeaderExportExcel(name_file)
    headers['Content-Type'] = "application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8; charset=ISO-8859-1; header=present"
    headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="' + name_file +'.xls"'
    headers['Cache-Control'] = ''  
  end
```

In My Rspec Controller I have this code

```
require 'rails_helper'
#TODO: add test controller
RSpec.describe SyllabusesController, type: :controller do
  describe "syllabus_program#update " do
    context "as an authorized " do
      before do 
        #@user = FactoryBot.create(:user)

      end  
    end  
  end

  describe "GET#download_syllabus_excel" do
    it "return succes response" do
      get download_syllabus_evaluation_system_path(format: "excel")
      expect(response).to  be_successful
    end
  end  

end
```

And my route is

```
  get 'download_syllabus_evaluation_system' => 'syllabuses#download_syllabus_evaluation_system', as: "download_syllabus_evaluation_system"
```

But when i run the test , i get this error

```
 Failure/Error: get download_syllabus_evaluation_system_path(format: "excel")

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"/download_syllabus_evaluation_system.excel", :controller=>"syllabuses"}
```

Whats the problem?

Comment: I don’t understand why you’re trying to render the excel file in a browser instead of using send_file or x_send_file to download the file after it’s been generated. Given the file isn’t going to be particularly quick to create, you could create it with a background job then download it at the time or request, rather than recreating it.

Comment: Try `get :download_syllabus_evaluation_system, {}, format: :excel`.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I tried with your sintaxis, but i have this error
ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)